# What's more appropriate here: Arrays.copyOfRange() or ordinary loop?

Tags: biginteger, java

Line 331 here ([openjdk's MutableBigInteger source](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7-gate/jdk/file/9b8c96f96a0f/src/share/classes/java/math/MutableBigInteger.java)) defines function toIntArray(). In general, MutableBigInteger is an array that can be, for example `{0, 0, 0, 0x12345678, ..., 0xffffffff, 0, 0, 0}`, with variables `offset` and `intLen` defining positions of start and end of non-zero values (actual payload of array). So, that function goes as follows:

```
int[] result = new int[intLen];
for(int i=0; i<intLen; i++)
    result[i] = value[offset+i];
return result;
```

As package already imports `Arrays` utility class, isn't it better (faster? canonical?) to replace all the for-loop with `Arrays.copyOfRange(value, offset, intLen);`?

In general, my question is about all related situations: is it better to use library methods when dealing with cases like this or there is not actual difference and it results in executables of nearly same efficiency?

Comment: Library methods look cleaner and are probably faster.

Comment: Maybe this piece of code was written _before_ 1.6. `Arrays.copyOfRange()` has only been there since 1.6.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not going to quibble with the openjdk implementation until I've spent some time profiling and figuring out why they might have made the decisions they made (they could be wrong, but my snap judgement is much more likely to be wrong).

However, as a rule, it is almost always better to use established libraries than your own home-rolled implementations.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with the library method not for efficiency but just for clean code.

Here's some information on copying arrays, [very useful](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue124.html).

What I take away from that link is if you don't need the speed, don't bother changing it.  The risk of introducing a bug and the tedium aren't worth it.